# Allowed memory size exhausted with recursive function

Tags: php, function, recursion

Part of trying to catch multi-accounts by same user, we place a cookie when users login. During login, first we try to read a previous cookie and replace it by a new one. Read and written cookies are stored in a database. When cookies aren't deleted, this system can be part of recognizing multi-accounts.

When searching for multi-accounts with a recursive function, we ran out of memory. When not used as recursive, it works, but sometimes a user has so many accounts, we only find them by repeating this function for all found accounts. 
It works when repeating this function max 3 times, but to be sure, this function must run, untill no multi-accounts are found.

```
function xtest_getOtherNicks($dbh,$nick){
    /**
        Find all duplicate accounts, based on cookie
    */
    $aOtherNicks = array();
    $aCookies = db\ct_getCookies($dbh,$nick);

    foreach($aCookies as $k => $aCookie){

        $aFoundNicks = db\ct_getNick($dbh,$aCookies[$k]['cookiewaarde']);

        if(count($aFoundNicks) > 0){

            foreach($aFoundNicks as $key => $aFoundNick){

                if(!in_array($aFoundNick['nick'],$aOtherNicks)){
                    $aOtherNicks[] = $aFoundNick['nick'];

                    //Recursive part
                    //$aMoreFoundNicks = xtest_getOtherNicks($dbh,$aFoundNick['nick']);
                    /**
                    if(count($aMoreFoundNicks)>0){
                        foreach($aMoreFoundNicks as $key => $aMoreFoundNick){
                            if(!in_array($aMoreFoundNick['nick'],$aOtherNicks)){
                                $aOtherNicks[] = $aMoreFoundNick['nick'];
                            }    
                        }
                    } */

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $aOtherNicks; 
}
```

I have searched for other recursive problems, but they were different then mine. Perhaps it is possible to change the SQL and let the database do the job, but i am clueless for that part.

table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cookietest` (
  `cookiewaarde` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `datum` datetime NOT NULL,
  `rw` enum('r','w') NOT NULL,
  KEY `cookiewaarde` (`cookiewaarde`),
  KEY `nick` (`nick`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

query for cookies:

```
$q = "SELECT 
            cookiewaarde
        FROM
            cookietest
        WHERE
            nick = '".sanitize($nick)."'";// will be converted to PDO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `$aOtherNicks` into recursive scope. Otherwise you wont break recursive loop because it will compare against empty array (found values always unique). This shuold work:

```
function xtest_getOtherNicks($dbh, $nick, $aOtherNicks = array())
{
    $aCookies = db\ct_getCookies($dbh, $nick);
    foreach ($aCookies as $aCookie) {

        $aFoundNicks = db\ct_getNick($dbh, $aCookie['cookiewaarde']);
        foreach ($aFoundNicks as $aFoundNick) {
            if (in_array($aFoundNick['nick'], $aOtherNicks)) { continue; }
            $aOtherNicks[] = $aFoundNick['nick'];
            $aOtherNicks = xtest_getOtherNicks($dbh, $aFoundNick['nick'], $aOtherNicks);
        }
    }

    return $aOtherNicks;
}
```

Comment: Many,many thanks! Especially for the explanation why your code works and mine did not.

Comment: @Terradon Recursive functions (especially where recursive call condition depends on current state) are more convenient within object context (class syntax). Object properties (including dbh) doesn't need to be passed around, because it has the same (object) scope as methods (class functions).